# How to get the url of previous page in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a chrome extension for which I need to parse webpage from which files get downloaded. The problem is that when I click the download link I am redirected to another page from where my file gets downloaded.Now by using **downloadItem.url;** I am able to get the url but the url is of the page which I am redirected to ,But what I want is the url of page which contains the downloading link .Is there any way that I could get the url of previous page or I have to parse each and every webpage to check for the download link?for eg [this](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=6645369)

Comment: Not a full answer, but you will probably need to hook up to something like [webNavigation API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation).

Comment: Can you pls explain a bit about how can I use webNavigation to do this?