# How to load a url and check the event of clicking of link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to load a url then check for a particular text of anchor and now I want to set an event of clicking of that anchar tag.How can I do it?So far my code:

```
$.get(y, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $(data).find('a').each(function() {
        console.log($(this).text());
        if($(this).text().indexOf("Full Text as PDF")>=0)
        {
         alert($(this).text());}
     });
```

P.S: I am trying to do this in a chrome Extension.
UPDATED CODE:

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener( function(activeInfo){
  chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, function(tab){
    y = tab.url;



$.get(y, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $(data).find('a').each(function() {
        console.log($(this).text());

        if($(this).text().indexOf("Full Text as PDF")>=0)
        {   alert($(this).text());
            $(this).on("click", function()
            {   console.log("link clicked");
                alert("link clicked");
            });
         }
     });
});
});
});
```

Comment: I'm afraid your question lacks minimal understanding. You are trying to get a copy of the page you have opened, bind an event in that copy you `$.get`, and then somehow expect that handler to work _in the original tab_.

Comment: It's an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) you have here. Please take a read of Chrome extension [architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) and [Content Scripts documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) to move in the right direction.

Comment: This is what I actually want!! [link]: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24857334/how-to-get-the-url-of-previous-page-in-chrome-extension) ..I wasn't able to do it that way so I thought of doing it this way!!

Comment: This way might work, but you need to operate on the tab itself. That's what content scripts are for. Now, step back from SO and take time to read the docs I linked you to.

Comment: Xan is right, unless you add the anchors as new elements to the document, the events won't be triggered

Comment: @GregK It's worse than that, this code runs in a context of the wrong `document` (in a background page).

Comment: Ok, just saw the chrome-extension tag.

Answer (score 0):

a small implementation is:

```
$.get(y, function(data) {
   $("#mydiv").html(data); 
   $("#mydiv").find('a').each(function(){
     $(this).on("click",function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         alert($(this).html());
     });
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vzg6q/

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that I am  understanding correctly what you are asking, you want to bind a click event to all anchor tags with a certain text. If so, then something along these lines should work:

Tested and working. http://jsfiddle.net/rvrF8/8/

```
$.get( y, function( data ) 
{
    $( data ).find('a').each(function () 
    {
        var theText = $( this ).text( );
        var desiredText = 'abc';

        if ( theText == desiredText ) 
        {
            $( this ).on('click', function ( ) 
            {
            event.preventDefault( );
            alert( $( this ).text() );
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah I want exactly this but I don't know why ,this isn't workin

Comment: Ill play with it a bit and see if I can get it to work

Comment: Thanks a lot!!I appreciate that!What might be the reason why its not working??

Comment: Hmm, not 100% sure right now, when you run it are you getting any errors?

Comment: no,I am not getting any errors but nothing happens when I click that link..I have attached an alert statement!!

Comment: Does it have anthing to do with the fact that I am writing it inside an extension event..just see the updated code..

Comment: I don't understand whats the difference btw your previous code and current code?Still not working for me!!

Comment: @PugsOverDrugs See my comment on the question as to why this question cannot work.

Answer (score -2):

```
$(this).live('click', function(event){
  // do something
});
```